# How to create a copy of a tmux session?

Tags: tmux

I created a tmux session named `template`, in which I did some hard configurations, which are not scriptable due to manually typed passwords that can't be in plain-text files for security reasons.

Now I need to do independent tasks in that configured environment, so my idea is to create N independent copies of the `template` session, one for each new task as needed. I would like to do something like:

```
tmux copy-session -t template -s task_1
tmux copy-session -t template -s task_2
...
tmux copy-session -t template -s task_N
```

So I won't need to repeat that hard configuration for every task.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that works for my case is to open a new terminal, do all the configurations in there, export relevant environment variables, and *then* start `tmux`, which will inherit the parent environment. Inside `tmux` I create one window for each task; each window will start with the configured settings.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "copy" of the session? tmux can't tell what you did in each pane after it was started so it can't really copy it, the best it could do is create programs with the same commands as you started the panes with and you can easily script that yourself.